# I Need a Mailings Tab

Tags: mailing

I do not have a "Mailings" tab in the menu at the top of my screen. How do I add "Mailings" to my list of tabs? See screenshot below, a "Mailings" tab should be there.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Can you check required drupal permission for role is enabled? Like Administer CiviMailings?
2. Navigate to Administer >> Customize data and screens >> Navigation Menu. Check if Mailings is disabled, if so right click and enable the menu.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Pradeep's suggestions, also check **Administer menu » System Settings » Components** to ensure that CiviMail is enabled.